# OpenERP 7: How can I add a listview with stock locations in product form view

Tags: odoo

how can I add a listview with the stock locations of the product in product form view. Or maybe somebody knows a function that returns the stock location ids of an given product?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In openerp no such king of function to give ids of product location.
But in openerp function to get how much product available in this location.
If want to get location ids of give product then you have to make your own functions.

Comment: you can find this function in  stock module product.py file function name "get_product_available"

Comment: yes i have found. so the way is going through each location and check if the product is there?

Comment: yes, and if product exits in this location then used this location id :)